# mypy: base class has no attribute x, how to type hint in base class

Tags: python, annotations, type-hinting, mypy

I recently discovered mypy and I want my code to be type checked with it.

I have a `Connector` base class:

```
class Connector():
    ... some methods, but no __init__ ...
```

And I have several subclasses, they are all connectors, but of different types:

```
class Siphon(Connector)
    def __init__():
        short_name = "S"


class Tube(Connector)
    def __init__():
        short_name = "T"
```

When I use these objects, I normally put them in a list:

```
c1 = Siphon()
c2 = Tube()
list_connectors: List[Connector] = list()
list_connectors.append(c1)
list_connectors.append(c2)
```

Now let's say I want to write a function to return all the short names of all the connectors, as a list. I'd write something like that:

```
def get_names(list_connectors: List[Connector]) -> List[str]:
    tmp_list: List[str] = list()
    for c in list_connectors:
        tmp_list.append(c.short_name)
    return tmp_list
```

When I do that, mypy complains:

```
error: "Connector" has no attribute "short_name"
```

Which is true, the base Class Connector doesn't have this attribute, only the subclasses. But all Connector subclasses will have this attribute.

How should I correct that? I can"t use a class attribute here since all my subclasses will need their own `short_name` attribute.

Should I use a Union in the type hinting of my `get_names` function (in my real life situation, there are much more than 2 types of connectors, and the user of my API could add his own)?

I'm also not sure I could write a base `__init_` function and override it in the subclasses, because the subclasses all have a different init

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You'd add that attribute to the base type; you don't need to give it a value:

```
class Connector:
    short_name: str
```

This uses Python 3.6's [*Variable Annotation* syntax](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/), which is new in Python 3.6 or newer. It defines the type of an *instance* attribute, not a class attribute (for which there is [a separate syntax](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/#class-and-instance-variable-annotations)).

You can use a comment otherwise, at which point you do have to give the attribute an initial value, and is a class attribute:

```
class Connector:
   short_name = ''  # type: str
```

Comment: But isn't it a class variable? Will all my ```Connector``` objects share it?

Comment: @Rififi Read the PEP linked. `var: Type` is an instance type hint. `var: typing.ClassVar[Type]` is a class type hint. Your instances will share the type hint only, not the values.

Comment: @Rififi: I've made it explicit that the annotation documents the type of an instance attribute.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using python 3.6 or later then

```
class Connector():
    short_name: str
    ...
```

should work. This doesn't actually exist in the namespace, but MYPY will find it. See https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/.

---

Another option is to do

```
import abc
class Connector(abc.ABC):
    @property
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def short_name(self) -> str:
        ...
```