# mypy complains about extended base class' attribute type

Tags: python, derived-class, typechecking, mypy

I have two base classes `A` and `B` that are defined like this:

```
class A(object):
    def common_function(self):
        pass
class B(object):
    def __init__(self, a: A):
        self.a = a
    def another_common_function(self):
        pass
```

Class `A` holds some management information, whereas class `B` holds some other information, which is based on the information contained in class `A`, and therefore it knows about it's instance of `A`.

I also have two derived classes `dA` and `dB` that are defined like this:

```
class dA(A):
    def __init__(self, t: B):
        self.t = t
class dB(B):
    def __init__(self, a: dA):
        super(A, self).__init__(a)
```

These classes (among others (`dA1`, `dB1`, `dA2`, `dB2`) ... that are similarly designed) are used for some special operation and therefore they need to store some more information, e.g. the t from the example for this pair of classes, other classes have different stuff to store.

The problem is, that mypy complains about the usage of `dB.a.t`:

```
class dB(B):
    def __init__(self, a: dA):
        super(A, self).__init__(a)
    def do(self):
        if self.a.t is None:
            print("something")
```

> test.py: error: "A" has no attribute "t"

The complain is actually right. `A` doesn't have an attribute `t`. I also told mypy that `B.a` is of type `A`, but in this particular case I use `dB.a` as of type `dA`, which actually has a t, but I explicitly told mypy otherwise.

The questions are:

1. Is this a violation of Liskov principle?
2. If not 1, is there a way to tell mypy that in this particular case `dB.a` is of type `dA`? Do I need to use a TypeVar?
3. If 1, is there a way to restructure the classes to not violate the Liskov principle as well as have the type checker be able to recognize the correct types?

I found the question [mypy: base class has no attribute x, how to type hint in base class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51191061/mypy-base-class-has-no-attribute-x-how-to-type-hint-in-base-class), however, the solution to extend the base class is not feasible, as this would make `t` available in all derived classes, not only `dA` (what somehow smells bad).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to ensure that `self.a` is of type `dA` by using assert:

```
class dB(B):
    def __init__(self, a: dA):
        super(A, self).__init__(a)
    def do(self):
        assert isinstance(self.a, dA)
        if self.a.t is None:
            print("something")
```

This assert is recognized by mypy, so that `self.a` is known as instance of `dA` afterwards and thus has an attribute `t`.

Answer (score 0):

You are able to specify the type of `self.a` in this instance by doing the following;

```py
class dB(B):
    a: dA

    ...  # Rest as before
```

It should be noted that I was not able to replicate the code provided by OP, as `mypy` was complaining that the second argument to `super` in `dB` was not of the same instance as argument 1. None the less, this should work for you as it did me in a situation similar to this.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).