# MyPy complains about "has no attribute" when adding new method to instance

Tags: python, mypy

```py
my_object = instance_from_external_module
my_object.prop = 2  # "..." has no attribute "prop"
```

How can I make MyPy accept a monkeypatch without raising an error in every single file of a large project where the object and that property are used?

I can't subclass whatever class the object is an instance of, because the object is complex and goes through a lot of third-party processing before being called.

Comment: HI, does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/51191130/11246056

Comment: No, because as I said I can't subclass my_object. It's an instance I import from an external module.